# StringBuilder Usage in Mail Sending Batch Java

Tags: java

I have a method for filling html data cells with data.

In this method I have a `mailBody` variable. I want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `mailBody`. But I don't know how to do this in my case.

Note: `tdClose` is defined as `"</td>"`

Where I want to use `StringBuilder`:

```
mailBody += "<tr><td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMid() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMdStatus() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getBin() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getCount() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getRatio() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMerchantName() + "</td></tr>";
```

My method:

```
public String createMailBody(List<VposNotificationBatchDto> notificationList) {

    StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder("<table><tr><th>ÜYE İŞYERİ ID</th><th>MD STATUS</th><th>BIN</th>");
    header.append("<th>İŞLEM SAYISI</th><th>ORAN</th><th>ÜYE İŞYERİ</th></tr>");

    String mailBody = "Merhaba,<br/><br/>Güvenli İşlem Raporu için işlem detayları aşağıdaki gibidir.";
    mailBody += "<br/><br/><br/>";
    mailBody += "<html><head><style>table{font-family: arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 75%;}th{background-color: #5fa8cc}";
    mailBody += "td,th{border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #dddddd;}</style>";
    mailBody += "</head><body><h3>Güvenli İşlem Rapor Detayları:</h3>" + header;

    for (int i = 0; i < notificationList.size(); i++) {

        mailBody += "<tr><td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMid() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMdStatus() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getBin() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getCount() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getRatio() + tdClose;
        mailBody += "<td>" + notificationList.get(i).getMerchantName() + "</td></tr>";

        String currentMailSubject = batchProps.getJobProps().get(jobName).getAlertProps().getMailSubject();
    }
    mailBody += endOfHtmlString;
    return mailBody;
}
```

Comment: A `StringBuilder` works like this: `new StringBuilder().append("one string").append("another string").append("one more just to be sure").toString();`

Comment: Pragmatic: 1. Just replace "String" (whole word) with "StringBuilder" 2. replace `+=` with `.concat(` 3. `+` with `).concat(` 4. add `)` to according line endings. But better: https://google.com/search?q=templating+framework+java (maybe you have one or other already "on board";)

Comment: And the most basic+elegant (maybe not best maintainable..it depends) solution (none of the top result) could be `String.format(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already used StringBuilder in header same you can use in mailBody.

```
public String createMailBody(List<VposNotificationBatchDto> notificationList) {

    StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder("<table><tr><th>ÜYE İŞYERİ ID</th><th>MD STATUS</th><th>BIN</th>");
    header.append("<th>İŞLEM SAYISI</th><th>ORAN</th><th>ÜYE İŞYERİ</th></tr>");

    StringBuilder mailBody =
            new StringBuilder("Merhaba,<br/><br/>Güvenli İşlem Raporu için işlem detayları aşağıdaki gibidir.");
    mailBody.append("<br/><br/><br/>");
    mailBody.append(
            "<html><head><style>table{font-family: arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 75%;}th{background-color: #5fa8cc}");
    mailBody.append(
            "td,th{border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #dddddd;}</style>");
    mailBody.append("</head><body><h3>Güvenli İşlem Rapor Detayları:</h3>").append(header.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < notificationList.size(); i++) {

        mailBody.append("<tr><td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getMid()).append(tdClose);
        mailBody.append("<td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getMdStatus()).append(tdClose);
        mailBody.append("<td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getBin()).append(tdClose);
        mailBody.append("<td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getCount()).append(tdClose);
        mailBody.append("<td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getRatio()).append(tdClose);
        mailBody.append("<td>").append(notificationList.get(i).getMerchantName()).append("</td></tr>");

        String currentMailSubject = batchProps.getJobProps().get(jobName).getAlertProps().getMailSubject();
    }
    mailBody.append(endOfHtmlString);
    return mailBody.toString();
}
```

If you are using eclipse then you can configure save action in that it will automatically convert string concat with string builder.

Comment: What I have confused that is mailBody continues with some new variables which is in the for loop so the lines are not constant as I defined above. That's why I was asking actually...

Comment: If values are dynamic/static it's good to use StringBuilder for better performance. String concat will occupy memory for each concat while StringBuilder uses like an array. More information can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html#:~:text=StringBuilder%20objects%20are%20like%20String,be%20changed%20through%20method%20invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You have already used StringBuilder in header which is perfectly correct. Then just the same way you can implement. just return **"return mailBody.toString();"**